# Transferring money from HSBC UK to TD Bank in Canada

Tags: canada, bank-account, money-transfer, international-transfer, online-banking

Lets say I want to transfer money to Canada from UK. HSBC-UK asks me to to enter the following information

- Payee account number
- Payments Canada Routing number
- Bank Name

---

Now the question : Should "payments Canada Routing number" be the TD bank branch which I initially opened my TD account or it can be any TD Bank close to my new address in Canada? In general when somebody transfers funds from UK to Canada should he always use the same routing number or he can switch the routing number to any TD bank branch close to his new address?

Comment: I don't know but if it were me, I would either transfer the funds to your existing account or set up a new account near your new address and transfer to that one.

Comment: @DanBracuk The question reads as if they are trying to do exactly this.